# GCM return 'error': 'NotRegistered' for chrome(push notification) while i did not unsubscribe

Tags: javascript, java, php, node.js, django

```
{'failure': 5, 'canonical_ids': 0, 'success': 5, 'multicast_id': 
5312901805636923901, 'results': [{'message_id': '0:1480575840991592%0a6d3c0af9fd7ecd'}, {'error': 'NotRegistered'}, {'error': 'NotRegistered'}, {'message_id': '0:1480575840992852%e6968224f9fd7ecd'}, {'error': 'NotRegistered'}, {'message_id': '0:1480575840992130%e8ee8671f9fd7ecd'}, {'message_id': '0:1480575840991594%0e35204cf9fd7ecd'}, {'error': 'NotRegistered'}, {'error': 'NotRegistered'}, {'message_id': '0:1480575840993735%b1274360f9fd7ecd'}]}
```

It is come when we unsubscribe any website but I did not unsubscribe.Please tell me what is reason?

Answer (score 0):

hey it is because google have removed GCM, so the app under development wont be able to get push notification from GCM.

SOLUTION:

1. you can use FCM in place of GCM to do the same.
2. You can use the key of FCM and use the same code of that of GCM it will work for that too.